# how to read float data from modbus RTU rs323 using c#

Tags: c#, .net

[i'm expected like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbhuK.png)I'm running this below code. it is run successfully but doesn't show me *accurate value* in *floating point*.
I need to handle memory registers with `float` data type
please any one can tell me how can i get value from modbus
[my output is that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBCYY.png)
I have a PLC connected to a PC through Modbus RTU (RS485). Between PLC and PC I have a RS485-RS232-USB converter.

```
mb.Open(lstPorts.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
        Convert.ToInt32(lstBaudrate.SelectedItem.ToString()),
        8, 
        Parity.None, 
        StopBits.One

  case "Float":
                    for (int i = 0; i < enter code here(pollLength / 2); i++)
                    {
                        int intValue = (int)values[2 * i];
                        intValue <<= 16;
                        intValue += (int)values[2 * i + 1];
                        itemString = "[" + Convert.ToString(pollStart + 2 * i + 40001) + "] , MB[" +
                            Convert.ToString(pollStart + 2 * i) + "] = " +
                            (BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue), 0)).ToString();
                        DoGUIUpdate(itemString);
                    }
```

Comment: Probably and endian issue, actually after i read your code, im like hmmm

Comment: `but doesn't show me accurate value in floating point.` this is the worst way to ask a question on stackoverflow. show what its outputting, describe whats its doing, explain why its not what you expect

Comment: i want what the data is (eg. pressure or temperature readings)

Comment: Explain what the values are not what you expect

Comment: you can see above two picture which i add now

Comment: heloo can you please explaine me

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to convert a WORD / DWORD to FLOAT.

The 1st is to consider it is already a float value that you receive and so apply some conversion, as you are doing well. So if it is wrong, you may try reverse 1st and second bytes:

```
int intValue = (int)values[2 * i] + (int)values[2 * i + 1]<<16;
```

Second option is to see what are **max** and **min** values for sensors and to see if you should not consider is as scale conversion. i.e.: `intValue * (max - min)/OxFFFFFFFF + min`. You can only know that from the documentation of your PLC...

Other point that I usually don't trust is the RS485-RS232-USB converter. I found a lot of cases when the converter does not retrieve data packets correctly. It means it may flush data differently from what is transmitted by the PLC.

I suggest you to explore another way to read data like, for example some streaming data. (I have no idea of C# way to do it).

Comment: documentation of your PLC is key here, we need to confirm what the bytes were supposed to mean, so that we can interpret them correctly, there is a good table of the options here: https://www.myscada.org/mydesigner-manual/?section=floating-point-numbers-2